# Meaning of " Welcome to it" in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> But then he smiled and stood up. “Wait! I
>   forgot about our custom! We never hang a
>   man until the women have been given a
>   chance to marry him. This way, ladies! A
>   husband for free! Who wants him?”
>   An old hag, terribly ugly, eagerly stepped
>   forward. “Do you have any money in your
>   purse?” she asked Gringoire in a raspy voice.
>   Gringoire looked down at her. “No—not a
>   single cent,” he answered truthfully.
>   The old hag scowled. “Hang, then, and
>   **welcome to it!**” she said in disgust.

Dose it mean one of the following sentence?

1)Hang him because there is no choice

2)Hang him and be happy with it

3) hang him because he himself want.

Answer (score 2):

More like, "Hang him and *I* will be happy with the outcome."

"Welcome to it!" is an expression I, personally, would never choose for that situation.

Usually "welcome" is used to indicate you are happy that a person is entering your home or your space, or you are happy with some situation or event: "This Spring weather is very welcome!"; "You are welcome to take any shirt you like."

But sometimes it does take on a sarcastic, negative emotional tone, "You *like* that painting!? Well, you are welcome to it." [I'm happy if you take it, because I hate it.]; "He's welcome to his opinion" [but I think he's an idiot]; "*You're* welcome to get food poisoning at this filthy 'cafe', but *I'm* going to McDonalds." [I don't like this restaurant at all.]

In this case I think the old hag was directly addressing Gringoire (the man who was to be hanged), and she meant "If you hang, I will be happy that will happen to you." She felt so much hatred that she said it "in disgust".